# Как отправить команду в exec

Tags: java, cmd

Как отправить команду в уже открытую exec программу? Например вводить значения в cmd

```
public void runFileCONSOLE() throws IOException {
        saveFile();
        runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        process = runtime.exec(new String[]{"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\JDKnotepadJC\\bin\\java.exe",saveFile.toString()});
        InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        new thread().start();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Надо сформировать строку с аргументами и затем передать ее в ProcessBuider.

```
String myagr = " java.exe -d  Myclass -cp .. "; 
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(myArg);
    pb.command(command)
    pb.start()
```

Comment: мне надо отправлять команды в уже открытую программу

Comment: В таком  случае , сначала надо  найти   id  процесса  программы и  дальше   пытаться тудда  что  то  передать.  JNI(JNA)  -   вам в помощь,  либо оргаизовать передачу данных  между приложениями с использованием   промежуточного звена или  файла

Comment: Зачем айди процесса? Я открываю программу из кода

Comment: по -другому.  У вас  ест ь java  прложение ,  и есть  ОТКРЫТОЕ  кем-то другим С++ приложение?  и  Ваша  задача передать данные в  приложение открытое  кем  то другим ,правильно?  Как  вы  идентифицируете чужжое  приложениев памяти  компьютера ,по   какому признаку?

Comment: Нет я программу открыл с помощью runtime.exec process = runtime.exec(new String[]{"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\JDKnotepadJC\\bin\\java.exe",saveFile.toString()});

Comment: я-тупой. Вы запустили  еще один java  процесс,  из  ууже  существующего java  процесса?  Вы  вызвали  java.exe  и передали аргуументом  вызов какогото-то метода saveFile.to String();  и вы хотите  в это  метод  передать данные ? я  уже  запутался.  каком  классу принадлежит  Ваш  метод?

Comment: вы не тупой, просто я вызываю runtime.exec и там программу не важно java или cmd, я могу считать все что происходит в консоли но как мне наоборот передать в неё команду если она уже запущена runtime.exec

Comment: В таком случае есть два вариаета которые я вижу. либо  полностью перейти JNA, либо  использовать батничек- обертку для конкретного файла( но это  очень костылеобразно)  .Т.е  создать  батничек вызывающий вашу программу и  потом  в этот батничек передавать данные

Comment: так... хорошо но как варить JNA

Comment: ох...  тут  я  не помогу,  я дальше  JNI не пошел, но смысл тот же. Есть классная книжка , очень классная, там  все черным по русский.  https://disk.yandex.ru/i/V_BA0onpm5e67A